# How to know if XML element contains an array programmatically in Java?

Tags: xml, xpath, soap, xml-parsing, complextype

I have an XML response:

```
<abc:parent>
    <abc:item>
        ...
    </abc:item>
    <abc:item>
        ...
    </abc:item>
</abc:parent>
```

That may also be with only one child element:

```
<abc:parent>
    <abc:item>
        ...
    </abc:item>
</abc:parent>
```

Previously the **parent** had an attribute 'SOAP-ENC:arrayType' to comfortably determine that it contains an array of child elements, but now the response is in previously described format.

Example of how it previously was:

```
<abc:parent xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="Struct[1]" SOAP-ENC:offset="[0]">
    <abc:item>
        ...
    </abc:item> 
</abc:parent>
```

Example of previous check:

```
private void parseNode(DomNode node, String xpath) {
    boolean isLeaf = true;

    for (DomNode childNode : node.getChildren()) {
        if (DomNode.TEXT_NODE != childNode.getNodeType()) {
            isLeaf = false;
        }
    }

    if (!isLeaf) {
        if (node instanceof DomElement) {
            DomElement eNode = (DomElement)node;
            String arrayType = eNode.getAttribute("SOAP-ENC:arrayType");
            if (!PkUtil.isEmpty(arrayType)) {
                // we have a node with an array of children
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have no control over the response message.

How can I tell for sure that the parent element contains an array of children? To me it seems it's not even possible with this result and information.

Comment: With what language ? With **XPath** ? How were you checking the attribute before ?

Comment: Java, XPath. Attribute check before: node.getAttribute("SOAP-ENC:arrayType")

Comment: Can you update your question with your java code ?

Comment: Updated with Java example to show how it was previously done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably do this by checking the number of `item` that you have, if it has more than one `item` you know it's an array :

```
DomElement eNode = (DomElement) node;
NodeList childList = eNode.getElementsByTagName("item");
if (childList.getLength() > 1) {
    // we have a node with an array of children
}
```

Comment: This is what I thought. But I can't know if it's an array if there is parent with only one child element (other than hardcoding that if-this-request-and-this-parent-with-this-child-even-if-only-one-child it's an array). So I changed my other code accordingly. Thanks!